# Docker Rebuild Container w/ New Application Code Only

Tags: docker, docker-compose

My Dockerfile looks like below. I am calling it from a `docker compose up` YAML file. If all I want to do is rebuild my CouchDB server/container with changes to the `local.ini` file, what would be the `docker compose` means to do that?

If I simply do `docker compose up` changes are not reflected in the server/container. I have to purge the container for changes to take effect. This is an issue because of the large re-download of the starting `couchdb:latest`image. All I really need to do is update that particular file and restart the server/service. Can Docker do that?

```
FROM couchdb:latest
COPY /configs/dev.local.ini /opt/couchdb/etc/local.ini
```

Comment: You can avoid redownloading by pinning the version, at least if it stays downloaded. Even then `latest` should do a quick check and not bother if `docker image ls` already has it.

Comment: Instead of copying your config into the container, why not mount it in your container? This way you can make all the changes you want with zero rebuilds.

Comment: I would like that very much! So how to mount `local.ini`? OK I think I found the docuentation on that will try. Thanks! https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/

Comment: It can be [a little tricky](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) but once you get it working, you can make changes by editing local files, no build required. Maybe only a service restart once in a while. Way easier. The [`volume`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/) specifier is where you start. One thing to keep in mind is there's Docker volumes (e.g. filesystems that persist between boots) and mounted volumes (local directory mounted into the machine *as* a volume) though the same option is used for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using docker compose. This should solve your problem:
docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  db:
    image: couchdb:latest
    volumes:
      - ./configs/dev.local.ini:/opt/couchdb/etc/local.ini
```

To reflect your changes, make sure to stop with `docker compose down` and do `docker compose up -d` again.